# WinForms Applications: Where is console.writeline() output rendered?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, console-application

I created a windows form solution and in the constructor of a class I called

`Console.WriteLine("constructer called")`

But I only got the form and not the console.. so where is the output?

Comment: or if you start your exe from the console and dont want to change your app manifest to be a console app, here is the real solution: http://www.nerdyhearn.com/blog/157/

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In project settings set application type as Console. Then you will get Console window AND Windows form.

Answer (score 95):

You should also consider using [Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx), that's probably what you're looking for. These statements are written out the trace listeners for your application, and can be viewed in the [Output Window of Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms698739%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
Debug.WriteLine("constructor fired");
```

Comment: I keep trying this, but nothing ever shows up in the output window except the usual build started build succeeded stuff.

Comment: @KyleDelaney did you switch from "Build" to "Debug" output using the drop down?

Comment: @Mr.TA - I don't know, it was over 4 years ago

Comment: @KyleDelaney What about now? :)

Comment: Works only in Debug configuration.

Comment: You need `using System.Diagnostics;` for this `Debug` to be known in the code, see [Debug Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug?view=net-8.0#examples).

Answer (score 20):

If you run your application in Visual Studio you can see the console output in the output window.

> Debug -> Windows -> Output

Note that the preferable way to output diagnostics data from a WinForms application is to use [`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) or [`System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.writeline.aspx) as they are more configurable how and where you want the output.

Comment: How do you configure how and where you want the output? I've gone to the debug options window, and under Debugging > Output Window > General Output Settings, "All debug output" is set to "On," and I still can't get anything to show up in the output window using those methods.

Comment: @Albin: I do not think this works with a WinForms application. Not sure why your answer was accepted by so many people because this question concerns WinForms (not console) applications running in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 16):

As other answers have stated `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` is the right call for debugging messages. But to answer your question:

From a Winforms application you can invoke a console window for interaction like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...

void MyConsoleHandler()
{
    if (AllocConsole())
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Input some text here: ");
        string UserInput = Console.In.ReadLine();

        FreeConsole();
    }
}


[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AllocConsole();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool FreeConsole();
```

I sometimes use this to raise a command prompt instead of application windows when given certain switches on opening.

There's some more ideas in this similar question if anyone needs it:
[What is the Purpose of Console.WriteLine() in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473902/what-is-the-purpose-of-console-writeline-in-winforms)

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you very much for posting this even though nobody specifically asked for it.