# Returning the name of a file to when using Process.Start

Tags: c#, file

I am using a non win forms program where I need to open the file explorer and return the file that the user selects.  I am using `Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select etc");` to open file explorer, but when I select a file it just opens that file.  Is there a way that when I select the file it will return the file path to a variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a form to a console app so that user can select file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553932/how-do-i-add-a-form-to-a-console-app-so-that-user-can-select-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure your approach is wrong. As the <strike>[documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/152457)</strike><sup>[1]</sup> states:

> /select,  Opens a window view with the specified folder, file or
>                     application selected.

So the `/select` command line argument only tells the explorer to pre-select the specified folder or file. It is not for returning any user selection.

I suggest to use [`OpenFileDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog). You can use this dialog even if your application is not a pure Windows Forms app. You just need to reference the needed assemblies (`System.Windows.Forms.dll`) and namespaces (`using System.Windows.Forms;`).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Link outdated: [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150602220856/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/152457)

Comment: The `OpenFileDialog` class also rests in the `Microsoft.Win32` namespace, so the reference to `System.Windows.Forms` is unnecessary.

Comment: Since this is a console app, it's better not to use the WinForms namespace, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I only read msdn where they say `OpenFileDialog` is declared in `System.Windows.Forms`. If it works without that reference...nice.

Comment: Here -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx. +1 for being able to understand what the OP wants :)